# How to use FileHelper FieldOptional

Tags: c#, filehelpers

I have added the FieldOptional attribute however, I still get this error

**Line: 1 Column: 117. Delimiter ',' not found after field '`<TrackDate>k__BackingField`' (the record has less fields, the delimiter is wrong or the next field must be marked as optional)."**

My Field Class:

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]

public class MaltaIn
{
    [FieldOrder(0)]
    public string MilesEventCode { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(1)]
    public string MilesEventName { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(2)]
    public string ThirdPartyEventCode { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(3)]
    public string ThirdPartyEventName { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(4)]
    public string ThirdPartyReasonCode { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(5)]
    public string MilesRef { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(6)]
    public string ThirdPartyRef { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(7)]
    public string TrackDate { get; set; }

    [FieldOrder(8)]
    public string TrackTime { get; set; }

    [FieldOrder(9)]
    [FieldOptional]
    public string OrderNumber;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very Novice of me.. I failed to read the error :(

After Track Date it should be

```
[FieldOrder(8)]
[FieldOptional]
public string TrackTime;
```